# Using xpath fetch multiple parent nodes

Tags: xpath

I have the following sample xml. Based on the manufacturer id I am looking to get in return all Product Names corresponding to it.

```
<root>
  <Component ID="88" BusinessID="ABC">  
    <Product_Name>Apple iPhone 4 16GB Black</Product_Name>  
    <Product_Description>Apple iPhone 4 8GB Black</Product_Description>  
    <Manufacturer ID="1122" xsi:type="MobileHandset_Manufacturer"> 
      <Name>Apple</Name>  
      <Description>Apple</Description> 
    </Manufacturer>       
  </Component>
  <Component ID="98" BusinessID="LMN">  
    <Product_Name>Apple iPhone 4 16GB White</Product_Name>  
    <Product_Description>Apple iPhone 4 8GB White</Product_Description>  
    <Manufacturer ID="1122" xsi:type="MobileHandset_Manufacturer"> 
      <Name>Apple</Name>  
      <Description>Apple</Description> 
    </Manufacturer>       
  </Component>
  <Component ID="77" BusinessID="XYZ">  
    <Product_Name>Samsung Galaxy 16GB Green</Product_Name>  
    <Product_Description>Samsung Galaxy 16GB Green</Product_Description>  
    <Manufacturer ID="1177" xsi:type="MobileHandset_Manufacturer"> 
      <Name>Samsung</Name>  
      <Description>Samsung</Description> 
    </Manufacturer>       
  </Component>
</root>
```

Thus using the ID 1122, i would like to get in return the following product names:
Apple iPhone 4 16GB Black
Apple iPhone 4 8GB White

Can you help me build the xpath query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this query:

```
//Component[Manufacturer[@ID='1122']]/Product_Name/text()
```

Or depending on what you are doing with the result, you might want to leave the "/text()" bit off the end.

If you need to get only unique values, and can use XPath 2.0, you can wrap the address above in the distinct values function:

```
distinct-values(//Component[Manufacturer[@ID='1122']]/Product_Name/text())
```